# Completion Handlers in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, closures, completionhandler

I have a problem I'm trying to wrap my head around relating to the use of completion handlers. I have 3 layers in my iOS program, the ViewController->Service->Networking. I need to load some data through API call from the view controller.

I have defined functions(completionHandlers) in the ViewController that should execute once the data request is complete and am comfortable when in implementing completion handlers when only two layers exists, but confused when in the following scenario:

DashboardViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var stepCountController: ExpandedCardView!
    var articles:[Article]?
    let requestHandler = RequestHandler()
    let dashboardService = DashboardService()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dashboardService.getDashboardData(completionHandler: getDashboardDataCompletionHandler)
    }

    func getDashboardDataCompletionHandler(withData: DashboardDataRequest) {
        print(withData)
    }
}
```

DashboardService.swift

```
import Foundation

class DashboardService: GeneralService {

    var requestHandler: DashboardRequestHandler

    override init() {
        requestHandler = DashboardRequestHandler()
        super.init()
    }

    //this function should execute requestHandler.requestDashboardData(), and then execute convertDashboardData() with the result of previous get request
    func getDashboardData(completionHandler: @escaping (DashboardDataRequest) -> Void) {
        //on network call return
        guard let url = URL(string: apiResourceList?.value(forKey: "GetDashboard") as! String) else { return }
        requestHandler.requestDashboardData(url: url, completionHandler: convertDashboardData(completionHandler: completionHandler))
    }

    func convertDashboardData(completionHandler: (DashboardDataRequest) -> Void) {
        //convert object to format acceptable by view
    }
}
```

DashboardRequestHandler.swift

```
import Foundation

class DashboardRequestHandler: RequestHandler {

    var dataTask: URLSessionDataTask?

    func requestDashboardData(url: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (DashboardDataRequest) -> Void) {
        dataTask?.cancel()

        defaultSession.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }

            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }

            do {
                let decodedJson = try JSONDecoder().decode(DashboardDataRequest.self, from: data)
                completionHandler(decodedJson)
            } catch let jsonError {
                print(jsonError)
            }

        }).resume()
    }
}
```

If you look at the comment in DashboardService.swift, my problem is quite obvious. I pass a completion handler from ViewController to Service and Service has its own completion handler that it passes to RequestHandler where the view controller completion handler (getDashboardDataCompletionHandler) should be executed after the Service completion handler (convertDashboardData())

Please help me in clarifying how to implement this. Am I making a design mistake by trying to chain completionHandlers like this or am I missing something obvious.

Thank you

--**EDIT**--
My Request Handler implementation is as follows:

```
import Foundation

class RequestHandler {
    //    let defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    var defaultSession: URLSession!

    init() {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Api", ofType: "plist") else {
            print("Api.plist not found")
            return
        }
        let apiResourceList = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        if let authToken = apiResourceList?.value(forKey: "AuthToken") {
            config.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization": authToken]
        }
        defaultSession = URLSession(configuration: config)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide your definition of `RequestHandler` type?

Comment: done. this simply initializes my URLSession with the required headers for communicating with my server

Comment: The code you have should work if you switch the line `convertDashboardData(completionHandler: completionHandler)` to `completionHandler` in `DashboardService.swift`

Comment: And about that comment: `//convert object to format acceptable by view` - if you want to achieve that, your `DashboardService` should also perform a role of an adapter, so the declaration of the `getDashboardData` method should look like that: `func getDashboardData(completionHandler: @escaping (SomeTypeThatAdjustsDashboardDataToFormatAcceptableByView) -> Void)`. And then you'd have to make this conversion in the `DashboardService`

Comment: where SomeTypeThatAdjustsDashboardDataToFormatAcceptableByView will be another function/closure isn't it?

Comment: `SomeTypeThatAdjustsDashboardDataToFormatAcceptableByView` is a type; `(SomeTypeThatAdjustsDashboardDataToFormatAcceptableByView) -> Void` would be a closure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case is more clear to use delegation, for example like this:

```
protocol DashboardServiceDelegate {
    func didLoaded(_ viewModel: DashboardViewModel)
}

class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dashboardService.delegate = self
        dashboardService.getDashboardData()
    }
}
extension DashboardViewController: DashboardServiceDelegate {
    func didLoaded(_ viewModel: DashboardViewModel) {
        ///
    }
}


protocol DashboardRequestHandlerDelegate() {
    func didLoaded(request: DashboardDataRequest)
}

class DashboardService: GeneralService {
    private lazy var requestHandler: DashboardRequestHandler = { reqHandler in
        reqHandler.delegate = self
        return reqHandler
    }(DashboardRequestHandler())

    func getDashboardData() {
        guard let url = ...
        requestHandler.requestDashboardData(url: url)
    }
}

extension DashboardService: DashboardRequestHandlerDelegate {
    func didLoaded(request: DashboardDataRequest) {
        let viewModel = convert(request)
        delegate.didLoaded(viewModel)
    }
}
```

Comment: I would assume that in implementation of requestHandler.requestDashboardData(url: URL), I would have to call delegate.didLoaded(request) ??

Comment: Yes, you would have to call it after decoding from json

Comment: Sorry I took so long to accept your answer. I kinda implemented the completionHandler method when you posted this answer. I now realize that I find the delegate method more cleaner in this scenario and implemented it I'm my code. Thank you